# Calling executeQueryAsync in each loop for sharepoint javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to update table rows with information from a Sharepoint list. So, I am calling executeQueryAsync within a For Loop and it only updates the last item, but not all.

```
var oRows= $('#dataTable tr');
for (i=0; i<oRows.length; i++) {
    var cCells = oRows[i].cells;        
    var oAISDelChoice = cCells[0].innerHTML
    var aAvailItemPromise = updateAvailabilityChoice(oAISDelChoice);
    aAvailItemPromise.done(function(oResult){
        cCells[1].innerHTML = oResult;
    });
}

function updateAvailabilityChoice(itemRef) {
   var oDeferred = $.Deferred(function() {
      var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
      var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Test Deliverables');
      var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
      camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'Title\'/><Value Type=\'Text\'>' + itemRef + '</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>');
      var AISDelList = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
      clientContext.load(AISDelList);
      clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
         function() {
            var listItemEnumerator = AISDelList.getEnumerator();
            while(listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
               oAISAval = "";
               var oListItems = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
               oDeferred.resolve(oListItems.get_item('DocType'));
            }
         },
         function() {oDeferred.reject(args);}
         );
    });
    return oDeferred.promise();
}
```

Comment: Doing this way will be complicated. But you can get all the list items from list on page load and save it in array. Then update the table cells based on choice selection in another cell.

Comment: Thanks, Ganesh - I was thinking of doing this initially.

Comment: Yes, that will be better performance wise. Making JSOM call on each selection will be overhead for application.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to collect all promises into an array and wait for all of them to be resolved:

```
var promises = [];
for (i = 0; i < oRows.length; i++) {
    var cCells = oRows[i].cells;
    var oAISDelChoice = cCells[0].innerHTML
    var aAvailItemPromise = updateAvailabilityChoice(oAISDelChoice);
    promises.push(aAvailItemPromise);
    // aAvailItemPromise.done(function (oResult) {
    //     cCells[1].innerHTML = oResult;
    // });
}

// Wait for all promises to be resolved:
$.when(...promises).then( function(){
    var resolvedPromises=arguments; // The array of resolved objects as a pseudo-array
    for (i = 0; i < oRows.length; i++) {
        var cCells = oRows[i].cells;
        cCells[1].innerHTML = resolvedPromises[i];
    }
} );
```